# Socket.io .on not working but server receives emit

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to get a basic socket.io app working. I've confirmed that the server recieves the emitted events through logging, and the server side signal receiving works, but the client side .on does nothing when the emitted event happens and is logged server side. Code below:

## Server

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  }
});

//Whenever someone connects this gets executed
io.on('connection', function(socket){
   console.log('A user connected');
   socket.on('test', function(data){
       console.log('received');
       console.log(data);
    });
   //Whenever someone disconnects this piece of code executed
   socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('A user disconnected');
   });
});

http.listen(4321, function(){
   console.log('listening on *:4321');
});
```

## Client

```
var sio = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:4321");
sio.on('test', function(data){
    console.log('client received');
    console.log(data);
});
setTimeout(function() {
    sio.emit('test',{'test':'test'});
    console.log('test messaged initialized');
}, 3000);
```

The server output is:

```
A user connected
received
{ test: 'test' }
```

However the client side does absolutely nothing. I've also done the emits from an outside script, confirmed that the server is receiving the event, but the client still does nothing. Any idea why the client wouldn't respond when we've confirmed the emit is received by the server?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in order for the client to receive the signal the server has to be the one emitting the event. If the client emits the event it will not respond to itself.